# Calculating determinant of a matrix

Tags: math

I need an recursive algorithm to calculate determinant of n*n matrix.

Comment: You might want to post some of your own code here to get some help as "plz give me codez!" doenst sit well with the community. Either that or it smells of homework and the first point still applies there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard Method for computing the determinant is [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition). Use a library like LAPACK in production code. There is absolutely no point in using recursion, LU decomposition is usually implemented by solving M = LU in closed form, and takes O(n^3) operations.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) has a formula for calculating determinants. It involves permutations, which can easily be generated recursively. Google has plenty of results on "[permutation algorithm](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENZZ360&=&q=permutation+algorithm&aq=f&aqi=g9g-m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)".

Comment: The formula with permutations has *n!* terms and is not usable for large n.

Comment: It's most likely homework and probably what his teachers expect, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point in recursiveness here.

This matrix operation can easily be implemented in a SIMD operation, can be divided into threads, can be very well calculated on the GPU.

Recursiveness consumes a lot of memory, and some systems have limits in recursion depths.

Answer (score 1):

```
    |a b c d ...|
det |...........|
    |...........|
    |...........|

= a * det(M1) - b * det(M2) + c * det(M3) - d * det(M4) + ... - ...
```

where Mn is the remaining Matrix if you drop the first row and the n-th column